# How to include custom files with angular-cli build?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

RE: Angular2 2.0.0, angular-cli v1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8

How do I tell angular-cli to include a file from `src/assets` in the root of `dist` when it builds?

We deploy to a Windows host and need to include a `web.config` file to tell IIS to route everything to index. We were doing this pre RC4, but with all of the updating it fell through the cracks (I don't remember how we did it).

I've been scouring the [GitHub repo docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) and haven't found anything of use in regards to this topic. Maybe I'm in the wrong place?

In the [ToC](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#table-of-contents), there is a bullet point "Adding extra files to the build", but it appears that section doesn't exist.

Comment: Basically you can copy files with npm. Just add copy command in scripts into package.json. Also check this http://lucasmreis.github.io/blog/npm-is-an-amazing-build-tool/

Comment: What I ended up doing (which also seems hacky): installed a file copy npm package, then added a value in the "scripts" section of "package.json" like this `"copy:webConfig": "node node_modules/copy/bin/cli.js web.config dist"`. I also added a post build script: `"postbuild": "npm run copy:webConfig"`. There were other issues trying to get the copy to work, but this did the trick.

Comment: Hmm got the exact same requirement with Azure IIS Rules and Angular CLI - also did not want to add more build steps if possible

Comment: The answers here are right, but if you need to copy different files per environment I recommend to read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59162533/3306960

Answer (score 87, accepted):

> ### Update
>
> The most current documentation on this can be found at:
> https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration
>
> #### Notable Changes From Below
>
> - The configuration file is now called `angular.json`
> - The path is now relative to the root of the project not `src`

The team has added support for copying specific files as-is to the output folder (`dist` by default) in a later version of Angular CLI (would be beta 17 or 19 - it's been in final 1.x releases for ages).

You just add it to the array in `angular-cli.json` like:

```
{
  ...
  "apps" [
    {
       "root": "src",
       "assets": [
         "assets",
         "web.config"
       ],
       ...
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

<strike>(Note that the path is relative to the `src` folder)</strike>

I personally use it and it works just fine.

<strike>As of beta 24, I have [added a feature](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/345930079cfea71fbdee0700e8c43d4f23ad5a3f) to Angular CLI that makes sure all `assets` files and folders are served from the webpack dev server when running `ng test` not just `ng serve`.</strike>

It also supports serving the asset files in the webpack dev server used for unit tests (`ng test`).
(in case you need some JSON files for the tests, or just hate to see 404 warnings in console).
They are already served from `ng e2e` because it runs a full `ng serve`.

And it has more advanced features as well, like filtering what files you want from a folder, and having the output folder name be different from source folder:

```
{
  ...
  "apps" [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "web.config":
        {
          // Copy contents in this folder
          "input": "../",
          // That matches this wildcard
          "glob": "*.config",
          // And put them in this folder under `dist` ('.' means put it in `dist` directly)
          "output": "."
        }
      ],
      ...
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

You can also refer to the official documentation: [Angular Guide - Workspace configuration](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration)
.

---

.

#### [FOR ARCHIVING ONLY] Original Answer (Oct 6, 2016):

This is not supported currently unfortunately (as of beta-16). I raised the exact concern to the team (web.config files), but it doesn't seem to be happening any time soon (unless you are forking the CLI, etc).

Follow [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1942) for full discussion and possible future details.

##### P.S.

For the JSON file, you can put it in `./src/assets/`. This folder gets copied as-is to `./dist/assets/`. This is the current behaviour.

Earlier in systemJS days there was another `./public/` folder that got copied to `./dist/` directly, but this is gone in Webpack versions, which the issue referenced above discusses.

Comment: This config worked for me: {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              },

Comment: According to the current angular assets configuration, You should just this object to your assets list: `{ "input": "./", "glob": "*.config", "output": "."}`
In this case the config file is situated on the same place with angular.json (on the root directory of the project) and after build it appears on the root directory of the project inside of the dist folder

Answer (score 176):

The "assets" property of angular-cli.json can be configured to include custom files in angular-cli webpack build. So, configure "assets" property value as an array.
For example:

```
"assets": ["assets", "config.json",".htaccess"],
```

above configuration will copy  config.jon and .htaccess into dist folder during the angular-cli webpack build. above setting worked in angular-cli version 1.0.0-beta.18

Comment: Needs to be under "apps" , example:

 "apps": [
    {
        "assets": [ "config/appConfig.json" ]
    }]

Comment: Looks like a true, but not work for me. "assets": "assets" and "assets": ["assets"] - work, but "assets": ".htaccess",  "assets": ["assets", ".htaccess"] - doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @gleb, add like  "assets": ["assets", ".htaccess"] , i think this will serve your purpose.

Comment: @MdAyubAliSarker, thanks, the problem was that I used angular-cli version 1.0.0-beta.17. 1.0.0-beta.19 works well for me

Comment: @Kizmar: When I try this with "web.config" it fails with "Module Parse Failed". "Module parse failed... you may need an app loader... etc.   Did you encounter this?

Comment: Ok, ignore that, was a type - it works. So the Web.config needs to go into the root of the Src folder and then the JSON file looks like       "assets": [
        "assets",
        "web.config"
      ],

Comment: In angular 8 -    
"assets": [ "assets", "src/web.config" ]
or it will throw the error "The web.config asset path must start with the project source root."

Comment: The "assets" array is in file 'angular.json', not 'angular-cli.json' for Angular 12, and from other answer I see it's working that way since at least Angular 8.

Answer (score 12):

**For Angular 8 readers**,

`.htaccess`needs to be `src/.htaccess` . See, below,

```
 "assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
     "src/assets",
     "src/.htaccess"
  ],
```

Make sure you have placed the `.htaccess` file inside `src` directory of your project.

> and the file to put that in is `angular.json`, not the `angular-cli.json`

(If you need a valid `htaccess` file, then you can find one in here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57126352/767625)

That's it. This should now be copied when you hit `ng build --prod=true`.

Hope this helps someone.

Cheers,

Comment: and the file to put that in is `angular.json`, not the `angular-cli.json` mentioned in earlier answers.

Comment: Still works that way with Angular 12 (2021).  The "assets" array is already present in the angular.json if you generated your project with Angular CLI. You just have to add your file in there.

Comment: Thanks, @waldrabe for checking against Angular 12. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

One solution (although in my opinion is a bit of a hack) is to declare a variable in your `main.ts` file that requires the extra file you want to include in the webpack build output.

EX:

```
import './polyfills.ts';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/';

/* HACK: Include standalone web.config file manually in webpack build
 *
 * Due to the way the beta angular-cli abstracts the webpack config files into
 * angular-cli.json and lacks current documentation we were unable to find
 * a way to include additional files manually in the webpack build output.
 *
 * For hosting on IIS we need to include a web.config file for
 * specifying rewrite rules to make IIS compatible with the Angular Router.
 * The one liner following this comment is a hack to accomplish this
 * and should be reviewed and corrected as soon as adequete documentation
 * is available for the angular-cli configuration file.
 */
const webConfig = require('file?name=[name].[ext]!./web.config');

if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

When webpack encounters this variable declaration statement in `main.ts` it will emit the raw `web.config` file as part of the build output:

```
                            Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                       inline.map    5.59 kB       2  [emitted]  inline
                       web.config  684 bytes          [emitted]
                 styles.bundle.js    16.7 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  styles
                        inline.js    5.53 kB       2  [emitted]  inline
                         main.map    5.36 MB    0, 2  [emitted]  main
                       styles.map    22.6 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  styles
                   main.bundle.js    4.85 MB    0, 2  [emitted]  main
                       index.html    1.98 kB          [emitted]
                assets/.npmignore    0 bytes          [emitted]
         assets/styles/global.css    2.74 kB          [emitted]
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset     Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
    index.html  4.45 kB       0
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

An ideal solution would be in the webpack configuration, but I can't make heads or tails of how the angular-cli is managing that through `angular-cli.json` as of yet (beta.16).

So if anyone has a better answer that extends the webpack configuration for an angular-cli generated project I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "scripts" section in angular-cli.json file. You can add all the third party javascript files there.

Comment: Yes, but web.config isn't a JavaScript file. Will it also copy that without expecting it to be JS and bundling it with the rest of the JS?

Comment: @Kizmar, Yeah, this won't work. It will try (and fail) to load it as js.

Answer (score 1):

Modify angular.json.
Add entry to assets array:

```
{
  "glob": "**/web.config",
  "input": "src/",
  "output": "./"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used **Angular version 5**,
So I tried create file called *Staticfile.txt* when running ng build --prod command.
make sure to give the file extension , otherwise it won't create the file.