# How to copy selected files with AngularCLI with WebPack when doing production build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My production build of my Angular2 app using Angular CLI with WebPack needs some files copied to the dist folder so I can deploy the app to our production (IIS) server.  Specifically, I need web.config and favicon.ico files copied from src folder to dist folder.  The web.config file is necessary so I can apply URL Rewrite rules for html5 routes.

I'm assuming we need to add these static files to angular-cli.json file, but not sure where to list these files so they are included in production build.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use the assets option? eg ```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.14",
    "name": "client"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "assets": "assets",
...
```

Comment: web.config has to be copied to root where index.html resides.  It's my understanding assets get copied to assets folder.

Comment: I guess this issue is relevant: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1942

Comment: @Yuri.  Thanks for the link.  looks like there is no fix for this issue.  hopefully it will get fixed soon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include custom files with angular-cli build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538464/how-to-include-custom-files-with-angular-cli-build)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (angular-cli v1.0.0-beta.26), if you want to copy files and folders to a build, you can list them in `assets` property in `./angular-cli.json` config file.

```
"assets": [
  "web.config",
  "favicon.ico",
  "some_file",
  "some_folder",
  ...
]
```

Example of the config in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mrkvon/34f903ee0b7f5e781f33bbef75747f85).

Place the `web.config` and `favicon.ico` files to `./src/` folder of your project.
You should be able to serve them from urls `/web.config` and `/favicon.ico`.

If you include folders, they'll need to be a part of the url, i.e. `/some_folder/some_subfolder/another_file.txt`.

[Angular-CLI README](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#project-assets)

[Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41755748/4551707)