# Whats the default path for static files in Angular2?

Tags: file, angular, static, thymeleaf, angular-cli

I'm currently working on a small Angular2 project. In my case i have to reroute some of the requests (like "/faq", "/aboutus") back to my old backend server to get some server side rendered thymeleaf templates. Therefore i'm using the built in proxy to reroute to my backende server. Sadly for some weird reason it **only** servers the **html** files **without** any **scripts** and **styles** or **images**. (i used the angular-cli to create my project structure)

Thats why i wanted to add these **static files into my angular2 folder** but i can't find the correct place to make it available to my application.
Does anyone else know how to correctly place these file inside the project structure ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 49, accepted):

According to the current [angular-cli readme](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration) (v1.0.1):

> You use the assets array in angular-cli.json to list files or folders you want to copy as-is when building your project:

```
"assets": [
  "assets",
  "favicon.ico"
]
```

By default the `assets` folder is configured for this, so you can place your files into a structure like

```
├── src
.   ├── assets
.   .   ├── file1.txt
.   .   ├── img
    .   │   └── image1.png
        └── css
```

and serve them from url path `/img/image1.png` etc.

If you're not happy with the default option, add a folder name of your choice to `angular-cli.json`, i.e.

```
"assets": [
  "static",
  ...
]
```

Create the `./src/static/` folder for your files and serve analogously to the default.

Comment: I got this error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'assets/images/test.png'. anything missing? Thanks.

Comment: @Rocky Don't serve it from "/assets/images/test.png", serve it from "/images/test.png"

Comment: FYI: for angular 4, you have to serve them with `assets/img/image1.png` etc

Comment: how do i serve html page?

Comment: I had to `../assets/logo.png` for angular-7

Comment: It's a  relative path to the directory of the file where you want to use it.