# How to change Angular favIcon in Angular 10

Tags: angular

I have tried all options specified in the link [How to change Angular CLI favicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817280/how-to-change-angular-cli-favicon)

The image favicon is not coming.

I made my image 32*32Ppx size and replaced it in src and tried and also tried keeping it in assests.

In angular.json I modified like this

"assets": [
"src/favicon.png",
"src/assets"
],

In index.html

The title is loaded as shown in the attached image.

[image]

Is there something I have to do in angular 10?

Regards,

Nagasree.

Comment: What do you mean with *is not coming*? In the browser? Have you tried clearing the browser cache?

Comment: all of that should work. probably your browser cached the old/default one.
did you try to refresh the cache?

Comment: Hi I have updated with the page. It is not even showing the old icon.Could you please check and let me know?

Comment: Easy way to change favicon icon is replace existing with your own icon.

Answer (score 5):

You can set favicon on index.html file.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy way to change favicon icon is replace existing with your own icon.

OR

You can change it by providing your favicon name in index.html and angular.json

Comment: I did it but it is not picking up the new icon

Comment: Make sure you clear browser cache. For me , it worked both way.

Comment: I tried first option and cleared browsing data now it is again showing Angular icon

Comment: After clicking reload on the image it worked thanks Sanjay