# How do I change the Angular icon with my app's icon for a PWA app hosted on Firebase when choosing the 'add to homescreen' option?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, firebase-hosting

I've created a PWA and it's hosted on Firebase hosting.  After clicking app-name-axdax.firebaseapp.com and logging in it gives the option to add app to home screen.  However, it's using Angular's icon and not my icon.  How do I change this so that when it's added to the home screen it's only using my app's icon? I don't see a setting in hosting?

I've browsed and searched the firebase hosting module to no avail.  I've also searched in Stack and I don't see where I can change the icon.  I did not see any documentation on Ionic's site either.

Comment: If you are talking about favicon ==> Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817280/how-to-change-angular-cli-favicon

Answer (score 0):

You can find the icons defined in the `src\manifest.webmanifest` file. If you don't have that file you may want to add it using Angular schematics

```sh
ng add @angular/pwa
```

[Progressive Web Apps in Angular](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/pwa) from the Ionic team is good resource for Ionic PWA info.