# Angular 2: 404 (Not Found)

Tags: json, angular

I created my app using `angular-cli`.
I wrote service `GameService` for getting data from json file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class GameService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getGames() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get('app/shared/games.json', options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

Also I created model `Game`:

```
export class Game {
    title: String;
    image: String;
    cost: String;
}
```

I imported the service and the model in my `AppModule`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { GameService } from './shared/services/game.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [
    GameService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Loading application I get an error:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/app/shared/games.json 404 (Not Found)
```

Below is structure application:
[image]

I don't understand where I made the error exactly. I searched and saw many questions and answers to it on stackoverlow but it didn't help.
Please, help me.

Comment: You have to put the `shared` folder in `assets` object in `.angular-cli.json`. Alternatively, try placing the json file somewhere else such as the `assets` folder generated by default from angular-cli.

Comment: See the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424907/whats-the-default-path-for-static-files-in-angular2

Comment: Many thanks! I moved json file in the `assets` folder and now I don't get any errors. :) Good luck all.