# Can't display some images listed in assets section under Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I've done my research and found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230473/how-to-serve-up-images-in-angular2) or [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424907/whats-the-default-path-for-static-files-in-angular2) answers explaining that I'm supposed to define my file in the *assets* section of *angular-cli.json* file. I've done it as follows.

```
"assets": [
  "assets",
  "mylogo.png",
  "favicon.ico"
],
```

Later on, in the template I do the following.

```
<img src="mylogo.png">
<img src="favicon.ico">
```

The first one shows as a broken link whereas the second (the default Angular icon) shows just fine. I can't understand it as both reside in the same directory and both are referred to in the configuration file.

What am I missing?

Comment: You probably have another `favicon.ico`. Also favicons tend to get cached longer than other assets. Inspect the build with developer tools to se where the `mylogo.png` is actually point at.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Could you elaborate the inspection part, please? How do I do that? I can see the console output saying that *http://localhost:4200/mylogo.png* is 404 but more than that, I'm lost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same Problem, but i wanted to display an custom Icon.
My Solution was deleting the facicon.ico and the decleration in .angular-cli.json.

```
"assets": [
  "assets",
  "house.png"
 ],
```

My implementation in HTML index.html

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="house.png" />
```

[The implemented custom Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7pFu.png)

Then Restart your Application.

Comment: It might be that the *ng serve* needs to be reexecuted (at least in some browsers/OSs). Also, it might help to clean the cache, just in case.