# Getting 404 error while loading a script from a local folder in to a component

Tags: angular

I am trying to load a java script file in to a component. If the file is copied outside the 'src' folder it is working fine, but inside 'src' folder it is getting 404 error. I tried with different scenarios but issue not resolved. 
[image]

404 error
[image]

Thanks
Vimal

Answer (score 0):

When you serve angular application it starts the server at port 4200 with directory `PROJECT_FOLDER/src` that is when you load the script in component it already in the src folder so just use `app/shared/...` instead of `src/app/shared/...`.

Answer (score 0):

I think Angular will consider those as static files, meaning that they won't load on compile time, but rather at runtime, and at runtime there will be on `/src` but instead only `assets` (or what you ask Angular to copy over from `src`.

You have 2 options here:

1- Moving your static files into asstes and then you can reference them as `/assets/payment/js/init-payment.js`.

2- Ask Angular to copy certain directory from src into build directory when compiling.
and that's done in `angular.json` file inside the `assets` array.
For more details see this answer here:

[Whats the default path for static files in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424907/whats-the-default-path-for-static-files-in-angular2)