# Different assets in cli config for ng serve and ng build [Angular 5]

Tags: angular, typescript, build, angular-cli, assets

Is possible to use different assets array when i use `ng build`?

```
"assets": [
  "assets",
  "favicon.ico",
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "../externalDir",
    "output": "./app/",
    "allowOutsideOutDir": true
  }
]
```

In my case when i use `ng build` i want to build only this:

```
"assets": [
  "assets",
  "favicon.ico"
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is an option to do environment specific assets. But you can make additional apps in your angular-cli.json which are basically just copies of each other, but with different assets. For example

```
// angular-cli.json
"apps": [
    {
        "root": "src",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "name": "devApp",
        "assets" : [
            "assets",
            "favicon.ico",
            {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "../externalDir",
                "output": "./app/",
                "allowOutsideOutDir": true
            },
        ],
        ...
    },
    {
        "root": "src",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "name": "prodApp",
        "assets": [
            "assets",
            "favicon.ico"
        ],
        ...
    }
]
```

Now you can build your assets differently by building a specific "app"

```
// dev
ng build --app=0
// or
ng build --app=devApp

// prod
ng build --app=1
// or
ng build --app=prodApp
```

Angular cli [docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/multiple-apps.md) on multiple apps.

Answer (score 4):

My case was to include different robots.txt file per environment. So, in the `src/environments` folder I created two files: `robots.txt` and `robots.prod.txt`. In `angular.json` include it in `assets` array and use `fileReplacements` as follow (I paste only the relevant parts):

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "options": {
      "assets": [
        "src/assets",
        {
          "glob": "robots.txt",
          "input": "src/environments/",
          "output": "/"
        }
      ]
    },
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        "fileReplacements": [
          {
            "replace": "src/environments/robots.txt",
            "with": "src/environments/robots.prod.txt"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using `@angular/cli: ~8.3.4`.

Comment: Angular never intended file replacements to work for files not included in the bundle. I don't believe this would work in Angular 9 and beyond. See this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16779