# Angular Cli - When need to have multiple applications within one project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've read many articles about having multi apps in one angular project but haven't know exactly what are the scenarios that need this feature to be applied.
i got throw some related articles like:

https://yakovfain.com/2017/04/06/angular-cli-multiple-apps-in-the-same-project/

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps

regarding of explaining how to set it up, one benefit I've got is:

> Having a single project with multiple apps allows you to run a
>   time-consuming npm or yarn install once and just modify the name of
>   the app you want to run.
>
> also ability to share assets files

any more clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: why not just have one application with two modules?

Comment: yes my friend, that's what i'm after... when i need to use multiple apps in one project , or let's say why not to have two apps in two project instead two apps in one project.

Comment: Great. I suggest reading this: https://johnpapa.net/introducing-angular-modules-routing-module/

Comment: This may not be directly related since its not technically multiple apps, but this [use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927131/different-assets-in-cli-config-for-ng-serve-and-ng-build-angular-5/47927367#47927367) requires 2 app configurations for the same app, where the user needed different assets for different environments.

Comment: @Sam thank mate, it's really great article from John Papa, but nothing related multiple apps i found!!

Comment: @LLai thanks a lot, as you said it's not directly related to what i need, but it really a case maybe i need in the future :)

Comment: Can you share a modules between apps? I have a module that contains common components that app1, app2, app3 use.