# How to make my angular app use edited config file after 'ng build --prod'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm deploying an angular app using `ng build --prod`. All I want is to let the user using the `dist` folder can simply change in `config.json` file in the `asset` folder so that he can set his settings and my app will use that modified `config.json` file.

Is it possible after I run `ng build --prod` to have a `config.json` file in the build folder that the user can go and directly modify?

If not, is there any better way to accomplish that using another strategy?

Comment: Can you give an example of such *user setting*

Comment: As like - 

{
    "baseUrl": "http://...",
    "skills": ["A", "B", "C"]
}

Answer (score 5):

I understand that you want to load configuration similar to environment.ts file. Advantage of environment.*.ts file is, it is embedded into product during compile time. So, you won't be able to make changes runtime. For that you have create separate configuration json file that can be loaded as soon as the app starts using "APP_INITIALIZER".

I think this stackblitz example will help.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-load-config-on-init

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, there are few configuration parameters that you wish to change based on environment. There are two approaches

1. Create the config.json file as you described and it should be fetched using HttpClientModule.
2. You can create a script to hold environment variables. Inside the same script you can build Angular project using custom webpack configuration. You can find detailed explaination at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BU5G_i1J5CA

Disclaimer: The video was created by me.

Comment: No like that. I want to change `config.json` several times after build. And obviously there are only one environment which is production

Comment: You can use the first approach then.

Comment: Well, then you are saying that I should fetch my json in some service and after build I can change my json file and the modification will affect my app then?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is very much possible. The best solution i would suggest is

keep your `config.json` in assets folder. As the `assets` folder is always copied to the dist folder. So every time you create a build the `config.json` will be available inside that assets folder under dist.
You can go and edit it as much as you want.

One more approach that you can follow is keep your config.json inside `src` folder and in your `angular-cli.json` or `angular.json` based on the version of cli include it in the assets array. like below

**angular-cli.json**

```
  "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "config.json"
      ],
```

**angular.json**

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
     "src/assets",
     "src/.htaccess",
      "src/config.json"
  ],
```

[See for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538464/how-to-include-custom-files-with-angular-cli-build)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I can change my config file. But that changes are not affecting my app. Issue is here

Comment: Ok then that is a problem with how you are  using it.  With any of the above approach you will have to code a provider which fetches this file via http before angular app is bootstrapped and save it in sessionstorage or a service etc. Because i have the same setup and it works perfectly fine. Let me see if i can add a demo..

Comment: Great answer +1